# Download Area for PDF Files - Prestashop

Tags: download, prestashop, area

I'm looking for a module, or an alternative solution, that allows me to create a download area from which the user (only if logged in) can download some files cataloged by type.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dedicated CMS page. After that in your theme, edit the `themes/your_theme/templates/cms/page.tpl` and inside `{block name='cms_content'}` you can add something like this:

```
{if $customer.is_logged && $cms.id == ID_SPECIAL_CMS}
HTML with your links
{/if}
```

Of course, this is a very basic solution that, for example, doesn't prevent people from sharing the links.

If you want to have files in the categories, you probably need to search for a module similar to this one:
https://addons.prestashop.com/en/customer-service/14500-provision-of-files-for-customers.html